# Replace All first 4 spaces with a tab

Tags: shell, sed

I am doing some documentation work, and I have a tree structure like this:

```
A
    BB
    C   C
        DD
```

How can I replace just all the occurrences of 2 spaces in the head of the line with `'-'`, like:

```
A
--BB
--C   C
----DD
```

I have tried `sed 's/  /-/g'`, but this replaces all occurrences of 2 spaces; also `sed 's/^  /-/g'`, this just replaces the first occurrence of 2 spaces. How can I do this?

Comment: `sed 's/^.* /--/g'`
yields:


```A
--BB
--C
--DD
``` - do you have to use `sed` for this?

Comment: any shell command is good for me

Answer (score 7):

The regular expression for four spaces at beginning of line is `/^    /` where I put the slashes just to demarcate the expression (they are not part of the actual regular expression, but they are used as delimiters by `sed`).

```
sed 's/^    /\t/' file
```

In recent `sed` versions, you can add an `-i` option to modify `file` in-place (that is, `sed` will replace the file with the modified file); on *BSD (including OSX), you need `-i ''` with an empty option argument.

The `\t` escape code for tab is also not universally supported; if that is a problem, your shell probably allows you to type a literal tab by prefixing it with ctrl-V.

(Your question title says "tab" but your question asks about dashes.  To replace with two dashes, replace `\t` in the replacement part of the script with `--`, obviously.)

If you are trying to generalize to "any groups of two spaces at beginning of line should be replaced by a dash", this is not impossible to do in `sed`, but I would recommend Perl instead:

```
perl -pe 's%^((?:  )+)% "-" x (length($1) / 2)%e' file
```

This captures the match into `$1`; the inner parenthesized expression matches two spaces and the `+` quantifier says to match that as many times as possible.  The `/e` flag allows us to use Perl code in the replacement; this piece of code repeats the character `"-"` as many times as the captured expression was repeated, which is conveniently equal to half its length.

Comment: @Babyy Because each repetition consists of two spaces.

Comment: this really works, thanks. I sorry about my poor description and glad you understand me. But this is so complex and I dont use perl, is there a shell way to sovle this?  sed  awk or something else?

Comment: Uh, it's not complex. Doing that in `sed` would be complex. I suppose an Awk script along the same lines could be created; look at the `match()` function to see how to obtain the length of a regex match.

Comment: `awk 'match($0, /^(  )+/) == 1 { s=""; for(i=1; i<=RLENGTH; i+=2) s = s "-"; $0 = s substr($0, RLENGTH+1) }1'` ... the `code` formatting seems to condense the two spaces in the regex there, so you'll need to edit it.